# How do you write shared generic views with the new MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

About a week ago I saw a blog post describing how you could write a set of shared Views in the Views/Shared folder that could be used by all your Models. The post also explained how to decorate the Model properties with validation rules and messages. There was information about the new Model Binding improvements. The examples take advantage of new functionality in the preview release of ASP.Net MVC 2.

For the life of me, I can't find the blog post or other information on how to create the shared views.

Can anyone offer a pointer to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ask and you shall receive.](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/04/default-templated-views.aspx)

I've been playing with this quite a bit in the past few days. In addition to generic, dynamic display of editors, details, etc., I've also implemented generic, dynamic modification of data. Essentially, Phil's sample project covers the GET side of things, and I've implemented the POST. I'm also looking into dynamically generating JavaScript in order to have a dynamic list using jqGrid. Stay tuned to my blog if you're interested in this sort of thing.